# Use Mockito to unit test a function which calls async function

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a method which calls async function:

```
public class MyService {
  ...
  public void uploadData() {
    MyPool.getInstance().getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    boolean suc = upload();
                }
            });
        }
}
```

I want to unit test this function with [Mockito](http://mockito.org/), I tried:

```
MyPool mockMyPool = Mockito.mock(MyPool.class);
ThreadPool mockThreadPool = Mockito.mock(ThreadPool.class);
ArgumentCaptor<Runnable> runnableCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Runnable.class);

when(mockMyPool.getThreadPool()).thenReturn(mockThreadPool);
MyService service = new MyService();

// run the method under test
service.uploadData();

// set the runnableCaptor to hold your callback
verify(mockThreadPool).execute(runnableCaptor.capture());
```

But I got error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.WantedButNotInvoked: 
Wanted but not invoked:
threadPool.execute(
    <Capturing argument>
);
```

Why I got this error, how to unit test uploadData() function with Mockito?

Comment: How does `MyPool.getInstance()` know about your `mockMyPool` and return it?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out a way by myself, since `MyPool` is an singleton. I added one public function `setInstance(mockedInstance)` to pass the mocked instance to `MyPool`. Then, it works. I know it is a bit "dirty", but if you have better solution, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Use [Dependency Injection](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) instead of singletons.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the DI approach you found of keeping a MyPool or ThreadPool field, you can also refactor a little bit to allow for dependency injection *in your method*:

```
public class MyService {
  ...
  public void uploadData() {
    uploadData(MyPool.getInstance().getThreadPool());
  }

  /** Receives an Executor for execution. Package-private for testing. */
  void uploadData(Executor executor) {
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        boolean suc = upload();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This might be even cleaner, because it reduces your ThreadPool to the level of abstraction you need (Executor), which means you're only mocking a one-method interface rather than your ThreadPool (which I assume is related to ThreadPoolService; otherwise, you can just accept a ThreadPool, too). Officially your `uploadData()` would be untested, but you could easily and thoroughly test `uploadData(Executor)` or `uploadData(ThreadPool)`, which are the moving parts most likely to break.

The package-private trick does rely on your code and tests to be in the same package, though they could be in different source folders; alternatively, you could just make the ThreadPool-receiving call a part of your public API, which would allow for more flexibility later.